# Appcelerator Titanium - hide keyboard is not working

Tags: dom-events, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

The below is my code ...

```
var textField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
  left: 20,
  width: 280,
  height: 40,
  top: 20,
  borderStyle:Titanium.UI.INPUT_BORDERSTYLE_ROUNDED,
  keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_NUMBER_PAD,
});

win.add(textField)
    
var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
 title:'Submit',
 left: 200,
 width: 100,
 height: 40,
 top: 70
});

win.add(button)

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
 textField.blur();
});
```

When I click on the button, the NUMPAD Keyboard is still there, it doesn't go away, anyone know why?

Need Advice.

---

Sorry for posting -> problem solved

Comment: Don't forget post the answer, it might be useful for someone else ;)

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted this code and its working fine.. On button click NUMPAD keyboard is not visible any more..

try cleaning you project and then build it ..

Answer (score -1):

missing this in your textfield "returnKeyType : Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,"

Comment: returnKeyType does not affect the hiding of keyboard unless the keyboard is NUMBER PAD on iPhone only. iPad always have a button to hide the keyboard.